# Prompting User to Take Picture on Desktop, IOS 6- and Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, dom, file-upload, windows-phone-8, camera

I have a page where I use a file input element (accept is image/*) to allow the user to upload a picture. On Android (and some of the minor mobile systems/browsers), it prompts the user to chose a picture from saved pictures or they can take a picture directly from the dialog. But for devices running IOS <= 6, Windows Phone and computers that are non-mobile (desktop, laptop and tablets that run desktop OSes such as Surface), it just prompts with a normal open file dialog, or just doesn't do anything in some cases.

Are there any browser-specific APIs that will allow me to prompt the user to take a picture and send it back to the server in the same way that the input box would? If nothing else, is there an IE-specific API to take a picture?

Comment: Wow. I just earned a badge called 'Tumbleweed' for this question; that *can't* be good.